# axlsx: conditional formating with multiple rules, with one condition applying to another column

Tags: axlsx

I would like to develop a conditional formatting in axlsx with at least one rule applying to another column.
I.e. I have text in column A (e.g. "A", "B", "C") and data in column B (e.g. "1", "2", "3"). Is it possible to build a condition

```
IF colA = "B" AND colB >= 2 THEN APPLY conditional formatting to colB
```

within the frame of axlsx?
I hope, my pseudo code makes my intention clear.
Best regards, and thank you in advance!